# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' & AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to upgrade spring-boot - 2.0.9.RELEASE.jar to spring-boot-2.7.2 & spring-5.0.17.RELEASE.jar to 5.3.22 , getting below error, any lead can help here, Thanks Advance.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at com.teradata.rest.dsa.Main.main(Unknown Source) [classes!/:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [DSARestProject-2.7.2.jar:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) [DSARestProject-2.7.2.jar:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [DSARestProject-2.7.2.jar:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) [DSARestProject-2.7.2.jar:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:106) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[activemq-all-5.17.1.jar:5.17.1]
... 29 more

=============Code snippet===============

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig
{ 
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }        
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity htt) throws Exception {    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(...).and()
        .httpBasic().realmName(...).and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: *Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one*

Comment: As stated by @Jens the error tells you that you can't have SecurityFilterChain beans aslong as you have a config class implementing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Perhaps you have the old config class from migration stil active? if so delete or comment said class

Comment: Ralan, Jens now I'm not using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, if u see SecurityConfig is not extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Can you please help me how/where is using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.